# QUERY syntax for using a 'cell reference' after the 'where'

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use submitted Google Form data in one spreadsheet to locate and retrieve data from another spreadsheet (tab in same document). [The Google Spreadsheet file is here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhNVNg1xSJ6-dGpvdFJGMmpuWExWeUE2SWhFQ21Wb3c&usp=sharing)

**The =QUERY statement I'm trying to use is below**

```
=QUERY(sheet2!A1:K; "Select B, C where A =" & B1  ; 0)
```

It works if I remove the **'cell reference'** from `where A =" & B1  ; 0)` and I replace it with a **'static value'** like `where A contains '123456' ")`

Any suggestions on 'how' to get the =QUERY to work using a 'cell referenced' value. The heading for the column being referenced is TEXT but the value of all rows below the heading is a NUMBER

Thank you in advance,

Todd

Comment: B1 is not a number, it is "Student ID #". Try to swap B1 for B2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is old but I had the same issue and thought my solution might help others. Adding single brackets round the cell reference worked for me.

```
=Query(sheet2!A1:K, "select B, C where A ='"&B1&"'")
```